# Using recursive_directory_iterator in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, c++17

I am trying to use recursive_directory_iterator in a Visual Studio 2017 C++ Windows form application but although I have tried many times and Googled extensively I can't get it to work.

Here are my includes:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <msclr\marshal.h>
#include "Form1.h"
#include <filesystem>
```

And in Form1.h I have:

```
#pragma once

namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

namespace ReadDir2 
{

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace msclr::interop;
// using namespace std;
using namespace std::experimental::filesystem;
```

And where I am trying to use the method:

```
for (auto& p : fs::recursive_directory_iterator("E:\\Pictures\\2013 HOG Test Photos"))
                {
                    String^ sub_directory;
                    sub_directory = marshal_as<String^>(p);
                    Console::WriteLine("Directory name is " + sub_directory);
```

The compile error message I get says that the method is not part of the `std::experimental::filesystem` class.
I have tried all sorts of combinations of the class name to no avail.

The language is set to C++ 17
Any advice will be most appreciated.

Comment: Are you setting the C++17 compiler flag when compiling?

Comment: I have C++ 17 in the language directive in the project properties.  Is that what is needed?

Comment: I don't understand what that means.

Comment: In the project properties, there is an option to select the C++ language version which I have done.

Comment: Remove `experimental::`, it is standard now.

Comment: Yes, I tried that - still get the same issue but thanks for your advice.

Comment: Found the issue - the #include <filesystem> has to be before the #include of the form in the first code box up top.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue: the #include of the filesystem has to be before the #include of the form.

Comment: Then it is missing *in* the form. Your headers should be independent and order-agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

You must include `filesystem` on the header, not on your source file. You are using the namespace in your header, the include must thus be added.

Same for the other missing includes.

Comment: Thank you - I have them correctly now and it is working fine.